# Injecting a session variable into an IService using Ninject (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have a decent size web app that I want to make multi-client.  So at the minute I have a User table and my plan is to add a ClientId field to that table and then I can restrict users to only see the data for the client they belong to.

In an ideal world, I'd like to try to bake the security for this in at the lowest level, so that it's difficult to accidentally create a feature that would cause a client to see another client's data.  So when I'm consuming services in the controllers, instead of having to pass the clientId everytime:

```
var messages = _messageService.GetMessagesByType(clientId, type);
```

It's automatic:

```
var messages = _messageService.GetMessagesByType(type);
```

I'm using Ninject to inject my services into the controllers:

```
    public static void RegisterTypes(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IMessageService>().To<MessageService>();
    }
```

My thought process at the moment, is to store the current user's clientId as a session variable and then somehow inject it into the IServices before they're consumed in the controllers.

However, I assume the RegisterTypes method is called once on App_Start, so how would I go about injecting it when an action is called?  Or is there a better approach to what I'm trying to acheive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly enough i know very little about both web development and asp.net-mvc in special. However, the following might be an acceptable solution for you:
(note: i've assumend the client id is of type `ClientId`. See [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/19/from-primitive-obsession-to-domain-modelling/) for a reason.)
Given:

```
public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    public MessageService(ClientId clientId,...) {...}

    ...
}
```

you can define a binding:

```
kernel.Bind<IMessageService>().To<MessageService>
      .WithParameter(new TypeMatchingConstructorArgument(
          typeof(ClientId),
          (ctx, target) => (ClientId)HttpContext.Current.Session["clientId"]));
```

which injects the value of `HttpContext.Current.Session["clientId"]` into a parameter with type `ClientId` into the constructor of `MessageService`.
Instead of `TypeMatchingConstructorArgument` you can also use the `ConstructorArgument` parameter, it matches by parameter name instead of parameter type.

Now to take things a little bit further so it works for other services as well, we can also just simply do:

```
kernel.Bind<ClientId>()
      .ToMethod(ctx => ClientId)HttpContext.Current.Session["clientId"]);

kernel.Bind<IMessageService>().To<MessageService>();
```

Note: you might want to consider adding (to the binding) a verification whether there's a session and whether it has the clientId set.

Also note: you would need to take care that the `clientId` is actually known (put on the session) before the service is instantiated (= requested by a controller or one of its dependencies).